# Simple length validation to a key in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm currently making a validation system to check the length of the key in my dictionary and remove any added value when it goes over a specific length but the thing is when I try to making it doesn't seem to work and . Here's what I've done

```py
team1 = {"Team Ahab":["Martin","Kaz","Simba","Davis","Yas",],"Score":[]}


username = input("What is your name:")

if len(team1["Team Ahab"]) > 5:
  team1["Team Ahab"].pop(username)
  print("This team is full so please join another one instead")

else:
  team1["Team Ahab"].append(username)
  print(team1)
```

Here's my ideal output

```
 username = "Paul"
  
 This team is full so please join another one instead
```

Comment: You haven't added the user input to `team 1` at the point you do the length check. Replace with `>= 5` and don't worry about popping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation logic validates the team after adding the wrong member and then corrects this error. Using this logic, you should always `append` the new member to the team **before** performing any validations:

```py
team1["Team Ahab"].append(username)

if len(team1["Team Ahab"]) > 5:
  team1["Team Ahab"].pop(username)
  print("This team is full so please join another one instead")

else:
  print(team1)
```

Alternatively, you could check if the team's size is **exactly five** before appending to it. Note that in this case yu should not pop the last member of the team:

```py
if len(team1["Team Ahab"]) == 5:
  print("This team is full so please join another one instead")

else:
  team1["Team Ahab"].append(username)
  print(team1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified code as below:

```
team1 = {"Team Ahab":["Martin","Kaz","Simba","Davis","Yas",],"Score":[]}
username = input("What is your name:")

if len(team1["Team Ahab"]) >= 5 :
    if(username in team1["Team Ahab"]):
        team1["Team Ahab"].remove(username)
    print("This team is full so please join another one instead")
else:
  team1["Team Ahab"].append(username)
  print(team1)
```

Changes:

1. Condition needs to be len(team1["Team Ahab"]) >= 5 and (username in team1["Team Ahab"])
2. list.pop(index) expects a index, not str. Here, you can use remove function.